VSCode - shift+enter treatment
I have VSCode installed in two windows machines, with the same extensions installed (Pylance, Python, and Python debugger).
I'm getting different results when pressing shift+enter on a selection:

On one machine, it runs the selection in the terminal (which is what
I want).
On the other machine, it opens up Python REPL and runs there.

No manual keybinds have been added on either machine, and the keybinds are the same. What's causing the difference?

Is this solely an extension issue?

@BlueRobin what do you mean? They have the same extensions

Looks like your question was answered on SuperUser - https://superuser.com/questions/1461655/vs-code-shiftenter-does-not-send-code-to-python-interactive-why  And it is more of a SuperUser question since it's not really about programming but about IDE use.

@Grismar thank you very much
